# Using Jdk 10 and Oxygen 3a

Tags: java

In the following program the 2nd and 3rd import statements are erroring out by the following statement - The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module: client.combined, com.google.common.

The following are the jar files I added to module path.

[image: Jar Files included in Module Path]

[Program with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhJtB.png)

[After compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMTpK.png)

This program was running successfully with jdk 9 and oxygen. But its is failing now. Please let me know what corrections I can do to use the webdriver in my project.

Thanks in Advance.

```
package javaExamples;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;



public class FirstTrial {
        WebDriver driver;   
        JavascriptExecutor jse;

        public void invokeBrowser() {

            try {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32_2018_april\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);// allows system to wait max 30 secs if it
                                                                                // completes before its fine
                driver.get("http://www.edureka.co");
                searchBrowser();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void searchBrowser() {
            driver.findElement(By.id("homeSearchBar")).sendKeys("java");
            // Thread.sleep(2000);//allows to wait for 2 secs. This is
explicit wait. System           // must sleep for 2 secs
            driver.findElement(By.id("homeSearchBarIcon")).click();

            jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            jse.executeScript("scroll(0,600)");

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Weekend')]")).click();

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            FirstTrial myobj = new FirstTrial();
            myobj.invokeBrowser();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is failing"?

Comment: Those statements give me compliation errors.

Comment: What are the errors? Please add the error messages into your question

Comment: is this is maven project

Comment: I am not using maven